# Repeating the click animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to display text when clicked on a state with some animation. The problem is the animation effect is running only for the first time the state is clicked and not on the second time. The code is as follows:

```
$("#maharashtra").live("click",function(){

    $("#mainbg").hide();
    $("#divmaha").animate({left:"700px"});
    $("#divmaha").show() ;
    $("#divguj").hide();
    $("#divgoa").hide();
    $("#divkerala").hide();
    $("#divassam").hide();
    $("#divmeghalaya").hide();
    $("#divarunachal").hide();

    $("#divmizoram").hide();
    $("#divkarnataka").hide();
    $("#divandhra").hide();
    $("#divtamilnadu").hide();
    $("#divraj").hide();
    $("#divjammu").hide();
    $("#divuttaranchal").hide();
    $("#divhp").hide();
    $("#divharyana").hide();
    $("#divpunjab").hide();
    $("#divdelhi").hide();
    $("#divmadhya").hide();
    $("#divjharkhand").hide();
    $("#divchattisgarh").hide();
    $("#divup").hide();
    $("#divorissa").hide();
    $("#divbihar").hide();
    $("#divwestbengal").hide();
    $("#divsikkim").hide();
    $("#divtripura").hide();
    $("#divnagaland").hide();

});
```

Comment: This hurt my eyes, either chain your selectors or add a common class to all the elements you have to hide

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: holy f**ing `hide()` chain

Comment: [Note that `.live()` is deprecated from jQuery > 1.7](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Couldn't you use a common class???!

Answer (score 3):

That's because your animation has already been performed. Now, introduce a "Reset" button and add reverse of everything in the animation so it moves back to its original place. Now again whenever someone would click that animate button, it'll animate.

Btw, you can compress this code. Combine the selectors and separate them with comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it on

```
$("#maharashtra").on("click",function(){ });
```

Since you havent provided your full code i have another guess that you may not have reset the animation.
after hiding all that stuffs.. are u showing all dose hidden stuffs before the second click.?

Comment: That will make no difference

Comment: then may be because you havent reset the animation.

Answer (score 0):

because animation get performed on first click. try this. you will get to know what the problem.

```
     $("#maharashtra").live("click",function(){
       reset();
 $("#mainbg").hide();
 $("#divmaha").animate({left:"+=700px"});
 $("#divmaha").show() ;


});
 function reset ()
  {
             //reset your element to original position here and then you dont need write +=700px you can simply write left:"700px" 
   }
```

Now your element will get animatte to left by 700px on each click if you want to.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chetandoke/QwWUn/